# Give value, return field name in matlab structure

Tags: matlab, data-structures

I have a Matlab structure like this:

```
Columns.T21=6;
Columns.ws21=9;
Columns.wd21=10;
Columns.u21=11;
```

Is there some elegant way I can give the value and return the field name?  For instance, if I give 6 and it would return 'T21.'  I know that fieldnames() will return all the field names, but I want the fieldname for a specific value.  Many thanks!

Comment: hey, so out of curiosity, which solution/method did you end up using / found convenient / elegant ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the structure contains fields with scalar numeric values, you can use this `struct2array` based approach -

```
search_num = 6; %// Edit this for a different search number
fns=fieldnames(Columns) %// Get field names
out = fns(struct2array(Columns)==search_num) %// Logically index into names to find
                                             %// the one that matches our search
```

Comment: `struct2array()` is not a standard function, is it?

Comment: @PacificStickler It is a built-in function, just not well-documented. Basically it gets data from a structure with numeric values into a numeric array.

Comment: please do share with me any official documentation that you could find on it on mathworks. Also, on a side note, I can't find it on the open source GNU implementation of Matlab, i.e. Octave.

Comment: @PacificStickler When I typed `>> help struct2array`, it gave me this help text - `struct2array Convert structure with doubles to an array.`. The question was specific to MATLAB and not octave, so I followed what MATLAB supports. I am not sure about the downvote on this though.

Comment: @PacificStickler Not trying to be noisy about it, but if you have down-voted this, could you explain the reason behind it. I try to better my answers as much as I could and would certainly do for this one too if the scope of improvement is conveyed. Please ignore this comment otherwise.

Comment: @Pacificstickler @Divakar Just to clear anything up over `struct2array`... It was part of signal processing toolbox in previous versions (as recent as 2013a), but in the current version it is part of the main distribution. (also the documentation is lacking, as Divakar showed)

Comment: Its an ongoing issue that some people can find `struct2array` while others cannot (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/337858). `which struct2array` shows that it is part of the `shared` toolbox which some people might not have. Finally, it isn't documented on the mathworks website either.

Answer (score 2):

**Goal:**

Construct two `vectors` from your `struct`, one for the names of `fields` and the other for their respective `values`. This has analogy to the `dict` in `Python` or `map` in `C++`, where you have unique `keys` being mapped to possibly non-unique `values`.

**Simple Solution:**

You can do this very simply using the various functions defined for `struct` in Matlab, namely: `struc2cell()` and `cell2mat()`

1. For the particular element of interest, say `1` of your struct `Columns`, get the names of all fields in the form of a cell array, using `fieldnames()` function:

   ```
   fields = fieldnames( Columns(1) )
   ```
2. Similarly, get the values of all the fields of that element of `Columns`, in the form of a matrix

   ```
   vals = cell2mat( struct2cell( Columns(1) ) )
   ```
3. Next, find the field with the corresponding value, say 6 here, using the `find` function and convert the resulting 1x1 cell into a char using `cell2mat()` function :

   ```
   cell2mat( fields( find( vals == 6 ) ) )
   ```

   which will yield:

   ```
   T21
   ```

Now, you can define a function that does this for you, e.g.:

```
function fieldname = getFieldForValue( myStruct, value)
```

**Advanced Solution using `Map Container` Data Abstraction:**

You can also choose to define an object of the `containers.map` class using the field-names of your `struct` as the `keySet` and values as `valueSet`.

```
myMap = containers.Map( fieldnames( Columns(1) ), struct2cell( Columns(1) ) );
```

This allows you to get `keys` and `values` using corresponding built-in functions:

```
myMapKeys = keys(myMap);
myMapValues = values(myMap);
```

Now, you can find all the keys corresponding to a particular value, say 6 in this case:

```
cell2mat( myMapKeys( find( myMapValues == 6) )' )
```

which again yields:

```
T21
```

**Caution**: This method, or for that matter all methods for doing so, will only work if all the fields have the values of the same type, because the `matrix` to which we are converting `vals` to, need to have a uniform type for all its elements. But I assume from your example that this would always be the case.

**Customized function/ logic:**

`struct` consists of `elements` that contain `fields` which have `values`, all in that order. An `element` is thus a `key` for which `field` is a `value`. The essence of "lookup" is to find values (which are non-unique) for specific keys (which are unique). Thus, Matlab has a built-in way of doing so. But what you want is the other way around, i.e. to find keys for specific values. Since its not a typical use case, you need to write up your own logic or function for it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The first line is giving me the following error: Error using cat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Comment: `fields = fieldnames( Columns)` would make it work I think. Rest of the code stays good.

Comment: yes, thanks @Divakar, `cell2mat` will give an error if the names of the fields of the struct `Columns` are strings of varying lengths. I've edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your structure is called `S`. First extract all the field names into an array:

```
fNames=fieldnames(S);
```

Now define a following anonymous function in your code:

```
myfun=@(yourArray,desiredValue) yourArray==desiredValue;
```

Then you can get the desired field name as:

```
desiredFieldIndex=myfun(structfun(@(x) x,S),3) %desired value is 3 (say)
desiredFieldName=fNames(desiredFieldIndex)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Alternative using `containers.Map`

Assuming each field in the structure contains one scalar value as in the question (not an array).

Aim is to create a Map object with the field values as *keys* and the field names as *values*

```
myMap = containers.Map(struct2cell(Columns),fieldnames(Columns))
```

Now to get the fieldname for a value index into `myMap` with the value

```
myMap(6)

ans =

T21
```

This has the advantage that *if the structure doesn't change* you can repeatedly use `myMap` to find other value-field name pairs

Comment: This approach assumes that the values are unique, which may not be the case in general. And hence, when creating this map, all duplicate entries in the `keySet` (which are the `values` of the `fields` in the `struct`) will get eliminated. Thus, this method will not find multiple `fieldnames` of the `struct` which have same values.